# If i die while my chill touch is in effect what happens?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

If I cast chill touch on my enemy, it says they can't heal until my next turn. If I am killed before my next turn, I don't have a next turn, so my next turn never happens. Does the chill touch no healing effect last forever?

Does my chill touch fade away immediately or does it wait until what would be the end of my next turn even though I am dead?

Comment: Related: "[What happens with effects that lasts until end of dead creature’s next turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/179908)" and "[Can Legendary Actions be used after a dead creature's turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176297)"

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate, it looks like it’s covered by the linked question.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I don't think the linked question actually answers this at all. It addresses the "does it just fade away?" part of the question but it doesn't address when "your next turn" is if you're dead and don't get turns anymore. The question Medix2 linked seems more appropriate as a duplicate.